# Error when filtering simple datatable when chrome debugger is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a relatively simple datatable in my html. I have defined a filter for each column. By typing a search word inside the input field of each footer cell the table is filtered accordingly.
**For cases that I tested**, the filtering itself seems to work as expected but after typing one character inside the column filter the focus on the filter input box is lost and I get the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?

**The weirdest part:**

**This happens only when my chrome debugger is open!**

I have searched the web for this type of error but all solutions were not applicable in my case. Although the functionality seems to be ok, I cannot live with an error that might harm in cases I did not cover. How can I resolve this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#search_origins_table-id');
  table.find('tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html("<input placeholder='Search " + title + "'/>")
  });
  table = table.DataTable({
    dom: '<"top" li>lt<"bottom"i><"clear">',
    lengthChange: false,
    fixedHeader: {
      footer: true
    },
    'iDisplayLength': -1
  });
  // Apply the search
  table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
      that
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    });
  }); //todo
});
```

```css
.this_product_link {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>yyyyyy</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.13/b-1.2.4/b-html5-1.2.4/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.13/b-1.2.4/b-html5-1.2.4/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.js"></script>





</head>

<body>

  <img id="loader" src="/static/img/loader_animation_large.gif" style="
      width:36px;
      height:36px;
      display: none;
      position:absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      margin-top:-18px;
      margin-left:-18px;" />
  <p><a href="/accounts/logout/">Logout</a> | <a href="/accounts/profile/">Home</a></p>

  Search origins:


  <table class="display" id="search_origins_table-id">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>From product</th>

        <th>To product</th>

        <th>To site</th>

        <th>To site id</th>

        <th>Search term</th>

        <th>When Saved</th>

        <th>When Added</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>

        <th>From product</th>

        <th>To product</th>

        <th>To site</th>

        <th>To site id</th>

        <th>Search term</th>

        <th>When Saved</th>

        <th>When Added</th>

      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/342320/"> 342320</a></td>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td>yyyy</td>
        <td>6000</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 9 9290cc Men&#39;s Electric Foil Shaver</td>
        <td>2018-10-27 20:05:47</td>
        <td>2018-10-27 20:05:47</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/286040/"> 286040</a></td>
        <td>xxxx_yyyy</td>
        <td>6002</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 3 3040 Shaver For Men </td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:45:32</td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:45:32</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/10/"> 10</a></td>
        <td>xxxx_yyyy</td>
        <td>6002</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 3 3040 Shaver For Men </td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:41:47</td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:41:47</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/608/"> 608</a></td>
        <td>xxxx_yyyy</td>
        <td>6002</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 3 3040 Shaver For Men </td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:40:04</td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:40:04</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/607/"> 607</a></td>
        <td>xxxx_yyyy</td>
        <td>6002</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 3 3040 Shaver For Men </td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:40:03</td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:40:03</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/606/"> 606</a></td>
        <td>xxxx_yyyy</td>
        <td>6002</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 3 3040 Shaver For Men </td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:40:02</td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:40:02</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/605/"> 605</a></td>
        <td>xxxx_yyyy</td>
        <td>6002</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 3 3040 Shaver For Men </td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:40:01</td>
        <td>2018-10-25 12:40:01</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/605/"> 605</a></td>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td>yyyy</td>
        <td>6000</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 3 3040 Rechargeable Wet &amp; Dry Electric Foil Shaver -- series 3 - 3040 wet &amp; dry</td>
        <td>2018-10-25 11:19:35</td>
        <td>2018-10-25 01:06:13</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/314628/"> 314628</a></td>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td>yyyy</td>
        <td>6000</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 7-740S-6 Wet &amp; Dry Electric Foil Shaver</td>
        <td>2018-10-18 18:08:58</td>
        <td>2018-10-18 13:17:54</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="/manage/product/10/"> 10</a></td>
        <td><a class="this_product_link" target="_blank" href="/manage/product/185150/"> 185150</a></td>
        <td>yyyy</td>
        <td>6000</td>
        <td>name;Braun Series 3 Proskin 3040S Wet &amp; Dry Rechargeable Electric Shaver For Men</td>
        <td>2018-10-24 16:25:53</td>
        <td>2018-10-12 13:44:48</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the javascript code according to [updated datatables example for filtering columns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
            $('#search_origins_table-id thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#search_origins_table-id thead');
            $('#search_origins_table-id thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function (i) {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');

                $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                        table
                            .column(i)
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });

            var table = $('#search_origins_table-id').DataTable({
                orderCellsTop: true,
                fixedHeader: true
            });
        });
```